# Running the same javascript for multiply onclicks

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I want to create a directory of links, each time the link gets clicked it restarts that links timer.

```
<Script> function countdown(elementName, minutes, seconds) {
  var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

  function twoDigits(n) {
    return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
  }

  function updateTimer() {
    msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
    if (msLeft < 1000) {
      element.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";
    } else {
      time = new Date(msLeft);
      hours = time.getUTCHours();
      mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
      element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits(mins) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits(time.getUTCSeconds());
      setTimeout(updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500);
    }
  }


  element = document.getElementById(elementName);
  endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60 * minutes + seconds) + 500;
  updateTimer();
}
</script>

<p>
<a onclick='countdown("countdown",
120,0);' href="https://www.bing.com/" target="_blank">Bing</a>
<div id="countdown"></div>
</p>

<p>
<a onclick='countdown("countdown2",
120,0);' href="https://www.google.com.au/" target="_blank">Google</a>
<div id="countdown"></div>
</p>
```

The problem that I have is that this will only run one countdown.

Is there a simply way that each link has it's own timer without having a script for each one?

Comment: Syntax error same id countdown should not used for both elements, instead of id, replace them with class='countdown' and in onClick function use onclick='countdown(this,120,0);

Comment: Countdown(this,120,0) will take care of the element that was clicked ..hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different div id's for countdown.

```
<a onclick='countdown("countdown1",
120,0);' href="https://www.bing.com/" target="_blank">Bing</a>
<div id="countdown1"></div>
</p>

<p>
<a onclick='countdown("countdown2",
120,0);' href="https://www.google.com.au/" target="_blank">Google</a>
<div id="countdown2"></div>
</p>
```